# Backbone Collection View doesn't show de html and values of Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using Backbone.js 0.9.10, 1.4.4 Underscore.js. 
When I call my html page there is no javascript error and the console shows that the collection was iterated.

However, the browser does not show my html I get the blank page. I log the result of html on  console and appears without replacing variables of model ​​by json, like that:

(I retired the signals (< >) in the tags to show that the html template that appears on console.)

my html come from view =
     p
        a href="#" id="remove-button" >Remover este Post/a
    /p
    h2 /h2
    p /p>

```
//HTML
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Backbone COLLECTION</title>
<script src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script src="../js/backbone/underscore.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script src="../js/backbone/backbone.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
</script>
<script src="../js/mvc/PostModel.js"></script>
<script src="../js/mvc/PostView.js"></script>
<script src="../js/mvc/PostCollectionView.js"></script>
<script src="../js/mvc/PostCollection.js"></script>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {            
        var postList = new PostList();
        var postCollectionView = new PostCollectionView({collection:postList});
        postList.fetch();
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/template" id="post-template">
<p>
    <a href="#" id="remove-button">Remover este Post</a>
</p>
<h2><%=title%></h2>
<p><%=text%></p>
</script>

</body>
</html>   


//VIEW
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {
    "click #remove-button": "removePost"
},

initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'removePost', 'refresh');

    this.template = _.template($('#post-template').html());

    this.model = new PostModel();

    this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
    this.model.on("destroy", this.refresh);
},

render: function() {
    console.log('PostView - render ');//ok

    var template = this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    return this;
},

removePost: function() {
    this.model.destroy();
},

refresh: function() {
    this.model.clear({silent: true});
    this.model.fetch();
}
});    

//MODEL
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults : function(){
    return {
        //some
        title: [],
        text: []
    }
}
});    

//COLLECTION
var PostCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
    this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
},

addOne: function(modelItem){
    var postView = new PostView({model: modelItem});
    console.log('my html come from view = ' + postView.render().$el.html());
    this.$el.append(postView.render().$el.html());        
},

addAll: function(){
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
},

render: function(){
    this.addAll();
}
});

//Collection with URL
var PostList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://www.mysystem.com/newproject/project/cadTarefas/recuperarListaTeste',

    model: PostModel
});

//My JSON
[{"title":"titulo_1","text":"texto_1"},{"title":"titulo_2","text":"texto_2"},
{"title":"titulo_3","text":"texto_3"},{"title":"titulo_4","text":"texto_4"}, 
{"title":"titulo_5","text":"texto_5"},{"title":"titulo_6","text":"texto_6"},
{"title":"titulo_7","text":"texto_7"},{"title":"titulo_8","text":"texto_8"},
{"title":"titulo_9","text":"texto_9"},{"title":"titulo_10","text":"texto_10"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change string in render view

```
var template = this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

to string

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I don't see in any of your code is where PostCollectionView's element is attached to the DOM.   It should either have a static declaration, i.e.

```
var PostCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#somediv'),
```

Or an external one,

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    var postList = new PostList();
    var postCollectionView = new PostCollectionView({collection:postList, el: $('#somediv')});
```

Or your controller is responsible for attaching the dynamically allocated one to the DOM after the View has been initialized.  One of those has to be true.

Secondly, in PostView, after you pass in an existing model, you destroy it with the line `this.model = new PostModel();`, which overwrites the object-local reference passed in with a new, blank model, which is why you're not seeing anything.

Comment: Hi Elf. Your tip about removing the line his.model PostModel = new (); been fundamental. Really json began appearing in print in the console.

But the html're not being displayed. Then I moved to the Underscore Mustache.js:
initialize: function () {
         this.template = $ ('# post-template'). html ();
         .....
     }

     addOne: function (ModelItem) {
         var rendered = Mustache.to_html (this.template, modelItem.toJSON ());
         console.log (rendered);
         $ ('# sampleArea'). append (rendered);
     }

It works fine! Thanks a lot!